# Benefit of parametric bootstrap over nonparametric bootstrap

Tags: nonparametric, bootstrap

Two part question.

1. What are the reasons to use a parametric bootstrap over a non-parametric bootstrap? For example, if the distributional assumptions are correct for the parametric bootstrap, are the associated confidence intervals narrower than those of the non-parametric version?
2. Some concrete references for whatever the answer to part 1 is.

Comment: Google something like 'Efron book on bootstrap' and pick a book that matches your level and fields of application.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Fictitious data.** Suppose you have a sample `x` of size $n = 50$ from a population
with an unknown mean and distribution. Then in R we have:

```
x
 [1]   7.1  26.9  41.1  22.8  18.2  19.5  37.7  39.1  17.5   3.3
[11]   6.1   2.3  12.5  11.7  29.1   9.5   6.5  26.1  33.0   9.5
[21]   6.5   0.5   8.0  24.1  79.4   4.3  39.8   0.3  36.8   2.2
[31]   2.1   3.0   9.9   5.0   9.4 181.3   0.7   4.3  14.8   0.4
[41]   3.1   7.3   4.7   1.6  26.5   6.9   2.7   3.6  10.1   0.4

summary(x)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
  0.300   3.375   8.700  17.584  23.775 181.300 

stripchart(x, pch="|")
```

[image]

There are many styles of nonparametric and parametric bootstrap confidence intervals. I will
compare three of them with two "traditional" CIs.

**Questionable t CI.** Obviously, the observations are strongly right-skewed. But suppose
we believe, somewhat too naively and strongly, in the legendary robustness of
t methods against departure from normality. So we try a 95% t confidence interval, which is $(9.57, 25.59).$ In R, this is part of the `t.test` procedure.

```
t.test(x)$conf.int
[1]  9.574129 25.593871
attr(,"conf.level")
[1] 0.95
```

**Nonparametric bootstrap CI.** Not knowing the family of distributions from which this sample was randomly chosen, we might try a 95% nonparametric
confidence interval for the population mean $\mu$ (which we
assume exists). To get an idea how variable the sample mean
$\bar X$ is as an estimate of $\mu,$ we re-sample many samples of size $50$ from `x` with replacement. For each re-sample,
we find the the distance between the observed mean $\bar X = 17.584$ and the mean of the re-sample. The distribution of
these many differences `d.re` can be used to find the
95% nonparametric bootstrap CI $(9.12, 23.82).$

```
set.seed(2021) 
# non-parametric bootstrap, re-sample from sample
a.obs = mean(x); a.obs
[1] 17.584

d.re = replicate(3000, mean(sample(x, 50, rep=T))-a.obs)
UL = quantile(d.re,c(.975,.025))
a.obs - UL
   97.5%     2.5% 
 9.12105 23.81885
```

**Parametric bootstrap CI.** Now suppose that we know that the population is exponentially distributed, with $X_i \stackrel{iid}{\sim}\mathsf{EXP}( \mathrm{rate}=1/\mu).$

Then we can make
a 95% parametric CI for $\mu$ by taking re-samples from
a population with mean $1/\bar X = 1/17.584.$ [Instead of
re-sampling from the sample `x`, we re-sample from
an exponential distribution 'suggested by' the sample `x`.] Of course, it would be better to know
the exact $\mu,$ but knowing $\hat\mu = 1/17.584$ is better than nothing.

For my fictitious data `x` the resulting 95% parametric
bootstrap CI is $(12.44, 22.13).$ This interval is narrower
than the nonparametric bootstrap CI because it is based
on the additional information that the population is exponential. [I did more re-samples here because
parametric bootstrap CIs with larger numbers of resamples
may be noticeably more accurate.]

```
set.seed(2021)
# parametric bootstrap, sample 50 from EXP(rate=1/a.obs)
a.obs = mean(x); a.obs
[1] 17.584
d.re = replicate(10000, mean(rexp(50,1/a.obs))-a.obs)
UL = quantile(d.re,c(.975,.025))
a.obs - UL
   97.5%     2.5% 
12.44381 22.13479
```

**Parametric CI, treating the mean as a scale parameter.** For some right-skewed distributions,
the mean $\mu$ is more accurately viewed as a scale
parameter than a location parameter. If we take this
point of view, it makes more sense to look at ratios of re-sampled means to observed means $\bar X^*/\bar X_{obs}$ rather than differences $\bar X^* - \bar X_{obs},$ for each re-sample. This style of parametric
bootstrap gives the reault $(13.66, 23.77).$

```
set.seed(2021)
# parametric bootstrap of ratios, sample 50 from EXP(rate=1/a.obs)
r.re = replicate(3000, mean(rexp(50,1/obs.a))/a.obs)
UL = quantile(r.re,c(.975,.025))
a.obs / UL
   97.5%     2.5% 
13.66134 23.76732
```

**If you know it: Exact CI.** However, if the population is known to be exponential, then
one can show that $\frac{\bar X}{\mu} \sim\mathsf{Gamma}(\mathrm{shape}=1/n, \mathrm{rate}=1/n).$ and 'pivot' this
relationship to make an *exact* 95% CI for $\mu$ of
the form $\left(\frac{\bar X}{U}, \frac{\bar X}{L}\right),$
where $L$ and $U$ cut probability $0.025$ from the lower
and upper tails of $\mathsf{Gamma}(1/50, 1/50).$
This exact 95% CI for $\mu$ is $(13.57, 23.69).$

```
mean(x)/qgamma(c(.975,.025), 50, 50)
[1] 13.57196 23.69111
```

Of course, this is the best 95% CI of the four on this
page because is strictly based on statistical theory.
Sometimes one may not know (or remember) that an
exact CI is available.

*Note:* The following R code was used to
sample the fictitious data used in this illustration:

```
set.seed(1203)
x = round(rexp(50,1/20),1)
```

Comment: Hi Bruce, very nice answer. Thanks. If the parametric assumption is wrong, can things go really bad?

Comment: For clarification sake, I mean the parametric bootstrap. I guess I'm trying to rationalize when to use the parametric bootstrap since in reality we never really know the distribution of the data. So would it always be safer to default to the nonparametric.

Comment: It is possible to know (or to be reasonably sure) that the dist'n of the population is normal, exponential, gamma, beta, etc. without knowing the parameters. Then suppose you can estimate the parameters of that distribution. If so, you can use the parametric bootstrap. Estimate the parameters and use them to est, the _specific_ dist'n from which to re-sample for a parametric bootstrap. In general, parametric bootstrap CIs will be better than if you use a parametric bootstrap where your info is restricted to the sample itself. // My param. bootstrap CIs above are narrower than nonparam. ones.

Comment: Please read sections of my Answ on parametric bootstrap again. I have modified the description, trying to make the role of the observed sample mean (`a,obs` in code) more clear.